# What is difference between .htc and .js file?

Tags: javascript, html-components

What is difference between .htc and .js file? Can we convert any .htc file to a .js file?

The problem is if we use htc to make png fixes, then we add htc to css file using

```
body { behavior: url("csshover3.htc"); }
```

But this is not W3C valid, so want to convert the .htc to .js and then use as a js file to attach in  so it will be W3C valid.

Can anyone tell me how to convert and use any .htc file as JavaScript file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Technically, you can use conditional comments to allow the code to validate.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

A hack is a hack, it's just weird that MS made this hack in a way that it's a valid hack.

Now, something else to consider - are you using a JavaScript library? Then you should be using the library to do this functionality, which would eliminate the need for the HTC (which needs JavaScript enabled to run).

Answer (score 41):

From the [Microsoft HTC Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018(VS.85).aspx):

> For Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 and
>   later, HTML Components (HTCs) provide
>   a mechanism to implement components in
>   script as Dynamic HTML (DHTML)
>   behaviors. An HTC is an HTML file that
>   contains script and a set of
>   HTC-specific elements that define the
>   component. The component is saved with
>   an .htc extension. This section lists
>   these HTC-specific elements and the
>   members they support.

Therefore, they are not just javascript .js files, they also contain a set of HTC-specific elements.

Edit:

Concerning the conversion from .htc to .js, I'm not sure if it can be done directly, but I've come across [this](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/) set of .js tools to address the same issues that .htc files are trying to fix in IE.

Answer (score 18):

A htc-file is a behaviour-file, have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018%28VS.85%29.aspx), [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents) and [here](http://www.webreference.com/js/column64/2.html). In a htc-file you can embed HTML-Code as well as Script-Code. Since a htc-file is not a pure Javascript-File, you cannot just convert it, but you may extract the Javascript-Parts of it, if you need.

Most HTC-Files I have seen so far are there to fix Internet Explorer problems, e.g. PNG transparency, which shows the sense of the htc-files: They can attach foreign properties to HTML-Elements, in this case, transparency.

Comment: The problem is if we use htc to make png fixes than we add htc to css file using :behaviour but this in not W3C valid soi want to covert .htc to js then us as a js file to attach in <head> so it will be W3C valid

Comment: If you use hacks you are not going to have valid code. That is the way of life.