# How to convert any .htc file into .js file?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html-components

How can I convert any .htc file into .js and use the resulting JavaScript?

For example, this is a .htc file: http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc.  I want to convert it into .js.

I want to convert it because the CMS I'm working with will not allow me to attach the .htc file. I think it's because of a mime type issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617667/what-is-difference-between-htc-and-js-file

Comment: @Garett - in that question no one replied about how to convert. and title was also different so i asked about only .htc to .js convert separately in this new question.

Comment: @Reigel - i added reason in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to convert **any** .htc file to an "equivalent" .js file. That is, it's not possible *automatically, in general*. However for the specific file you've posted, you could convert it using jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event.

But anyway, there's plenty of Javascript-only libraries that do the "border-radius" thing, why do you need to specific convert *this one*? A quick google search turns up dozens.

Comment: Thanks for reply . ok then this conversion then i will go for other solution

Comment: it's not possible so i selected your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some interesting information regarding conversion of HTC to JavaScript objects in this blog: http://ehudpardo.blogspot.com/2011/09/part-1-converting-htc-behaviors-to.html