# what is HTC files in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I just find out some htc files in my solution with some script inside what does those file do ? Is it possible to remove them. the using inside like behavior link inside of CSS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTC reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018%28VS.85%29.aspx) from MSDN:

> For Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 and later, HTML Components (HTCs)
>   provide a mechanism to implement components in script as Dynamic HTML
>   (DHTML) behaviors. An HTC is an HTML file that contains script and a
>   set of HTC-specific elements that define the component. The component
>   is saved with an .htc extension. This section lists these HTC-specific
>   elements and the members they support.

And maybe [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1617691/276235) can be of value.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely there to support CSS features unavailable in older versions of IE.

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/htc

Comment: They are behavior files and have their own custom MIME type. As jrummell said, they add support for things IE (IE 9, IE 8, 7, etc) don't support. You'll find that these are often CSS3 things but could be CSS2 things as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.filefacts.net/htc-file-extension

Files that use the file extension .htc are HTML Component Files which are HTML pages that are wrapped in descriptors that define properties etc that are used by the component, an apt description can be found on the w3.org website which states "HTC is literally a normal HTML file with a few defined XML elements inserted in the document"

Answer (score 0):

I have only used an htc file to allow IE (< 9) to draw rounded corners, along with the border-radius property. This is not a recommended practice though. It depends on your priorities: if you prefer efficiency over design, I wouldn't use those files.